# Random "The active directory domain services is currently unavailable" error

Tags: find, services, domain, windows-11

[image: error message]

This error started appearing today, seemingly at random times, while I'm working, browsing or gaming. The following 2 windows open. I tried finding more info using Process Explorer and apparently the windows belong to rundll32.exe with GUID `16006700-87AD-11D0-9140-00AA00C16E65` DsFindComputer. Is it possible to find the source of this error? I am not doing anything particular when it occurs. I am on Windows 11 64 bit.

Comment: Does [Fix The Active Directory Domain Services is currently unavailable](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/active-directory-domain-services-is-currently-unavailable) answer you question?

Comment: I tried running the troubleshooter but the error still occurred again. I didn't try taking ownership of a regedit folder though, just done that. I am not really sure that the problem is printer related though, because from what I've seen when that error occurs, it opens the "Find Printers" application, not "Find Computers" as is with my case.

Comment: Also having this issue. I notice a command prompt window sometimes pops up first. Feels a bit virusy to me. Ever find the fix @keklord ?